# software suggestion for drawing software diagrams

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-recommendation

i am new to Ubuntu.
need a suggestion for software to making **ERD,class & level diagrams in Final year project

Answer (score 0):

Dia is a popular one. It doesn't really have a way to export/import to SQL though, in case you want that from your ERD diagram editor. It should be able to draw whatever kind of diagram you want fairly easily though.

If you need Database interaction try mysql-workbench. It claims to let you mess with the schema of an actual connected database as an ERD, though I haven't used this feature myself.

Both are in the Ubuntu software repos.